# At what execution level will MySQL utilize the index for ORDER BY?

Tags: mysql, sql

I would like to understand at what point in time will MySQL use the indexed column when using ORDER BY.

For example, the query

```
SELECT * FROM A
INNER JOIN B ON B.id = A.id
WHERE A.status = 1 AND A.name = 'Mike' AND A.created_on BETWEEN '2014-10-01 00:00:00' AND NOW()
ORDER BY A.accessed_on DESC
```

Based on my knowledge a good index for the above query is an index on table A `(id, status, name created_on, accessed_on)` and another on `B.id`.

I also understand that SQL execution follow the order below. but I am not sure how the order selection and order works.

1. FROM clause
2. WHERE clause
3. GROUP BY clause
4. HAVING clause
5. SELECT clause
6. ORDER BY clause

**Question**

Is will it be better to start the index with the `id` column or in this case is does not matter since `WHERE` is executed first before the JOIN? or should it be

Second question the column accessed_on should it be at the beginning of the index combination, end or the middle? or should the `id` column come after all the columns in the `WHERE` clause?

I appreciate a detailed answer so I can understand the execution level of MySQL/SQL

**UPDATED**

I added few million records to both tables A and B then I have added multiple indexes to see which would be the best index. But, MySQL seems to like the index id_2 `(ie. (status, name, created_on, id, accessed_on))`

It seems to be applying the where and it will figure out that it would need and index on status, name, created_on then it apples the `INNER JOIN` and it will use the `id` index followed by the first 3. Finally, it will look for accessed_on as the last column. so the index `(status, name, created_on, id, accessed_on)` fits the same execution order

Here is the tables structures

```
CREATE TABLE `a` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `status` int(2) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `created_on` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `accessed_on` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `status` (`status`,`name`),
  KEY `status_2` (`status`,`name`,`created_on`),
  KEY `status_3` (`status`,`name`,`created_on`,`accessed_on`),
  KEY `status_4` (`status`,`name`,`accessed_on`),
  KEY `id` (`id`,`status`,`name`,`created_on`,`accessed_on`),
  KEY `id_2` (`status`,`name`,`created_on`,`id`,`accessed_on`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3135750 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8


CREATE TABLE `b` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3012644 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Comment: You can use `EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM A ...` to see what keys are being just and so on.

Answer (score 1):

The best indexes for this query is: `A(status, name, created_on)` and `B(id)`.  These indexes will satisfy the `where` clause and use the index for the join to `B`.

This index will not be used for sorting.  There are two major impediments to using any index for sorting.  The first is the join.  The second is the non-equality on `created_on`.  Some databases might figure out to use an index on `A(status, name, accessed_on)`, but I don't think MySQL is smart enough for that.

You don't want `id` as the first column in the index.  This precludes using the index to filter on `A`, because `id` is used for the `join` rather than in the `where`.

Comment: so you took out the id column from the index. Will this slow the query down since the join will have to be done with no index? Or will it in this case use an index for the where and another for the join from the same table?

Comment: Please check my updated question. MySQL seems to think the index with the follow order is the best fit `(status, name, created_on, id, accessed_on)`

Comment: @Mike . . . I think that is just so it has all the columns needed for the bulk of the query in the index.  That index covers everything except the `select *`.  If you use this index, does it still do a file sort for the query?

Comment: yes it does (Using where; Using index; Using filesort)

Comment: @Mike . . . I suspected that would be the case.  There is probably very little difference between the recommended index and the index I suggest.

Comment: When I use FORCE INDEX(status_4) which is what you suggested the query is only using WHERE. it is not using file sort. However, it examines about 4000 rows more. Is this considered a better index since it is not using a file sort?

Comment: @Mike . . . "better" is determined by whether the query runs faster.  Which way performs better?

Comment: It is difficult to find the best index as all indexed are being returned about the same speed. 1.545  to 1.763  and they query that runs in 1.545 is when using MySQL recommended "id" index.

Comment: @Mike . . . The MySQL index is a covering index, meaning that it has all the columns in the table used by the query (which is all of them).  That explains why it is a bit faster.  The improvement has nothing to do with speeding the sort.